# filling dropdown menu with xml and view the result in a html form

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

**I have this xml file (chapter.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <chapter>
     <lesson_1>message 1</lesson_1> 
     <lesson_2>message 2</lesson_2>
     <lesson_3>message 3</lesson_3>
     <lesson_4>message 4</lesson_4>
     <lesson_5>message 5</lesson_5>
     <lesson_6>message 6</lesson_6>
     <lesson_7>message 7</lesson_7>
     <lesson_8>message 8</lesson_8>
     <lesson_9>message 9</lesson_9>
     <lesson_10>message 10</lesson_10>
     <lesson_11>message 11</lesson_11>
</chapter>
```

**and this is the html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>

    //load xml document
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(numders)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xhttp.open("GET",numders,false);
 xhttp.send();
 return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("chapter.xml");
M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lesson_1");
for (i=0;i<M.length;i++)
{
document.write(M[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("<br />");
} 
</script>

<form  id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="">
<label for="textfield1"></label>
<input style="border-style: inset" maxlength="70" size="90" type="text" name="" id="" />
</form>

<table>
<p style="font-family:'Monotype Corsiva'"  align="right">chapter              
<select style="width:100px" name="lessons">
           <option>lesson_1</option>
           <option>lesson_2</option>
           <option>lesson_3</option>
           <option>lesson_4</option>
           <option>lesson_5</option>
           <option>lesson_6</option>
           <option>lesson_7</option>
           <option>lesson_8</option>
           <option>lesson_9</option>
           <option>lesson_10</option>
           <option>lesson_11</option>
</select>
</p>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

When i choose from dropdown list menu the first option "lesson _1", i want to load from xml document "message 1" in the form above, etc the second option "lesson _2" to load from xml "message 2"...

any suggestion for my problem?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a very outdated tutorial/book.

This line of code in particular shows it clearly

```
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

You should consider getting rid of the tutorial and use a modern toolkit/framework like jQuery, mootools or YUI, which has this built in (and makes it a hella lot easier for yourself)

the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) offers a great introduction to [using AJAX with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me%3a_Using_Ajax), which shows you a snippet, that is easy to understand and work with.

Comment: yes you have right, but i am new in web programming and now step by step i learn things. and i need some help

Answer (score 0):

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
for (int i = 0; i < x.childNodes.length; i ++) {
 addOption(x.childNodes[i].textContent);
}
```

`addOption` is your js function for adding options.

Comment: it's stack in loop for. Because of "int". why? and about the js function you mean something like this: <option value"addOption(x.childNodes[i].textContent)">lesson_1</option>        and how the form show the result? it's not necessary to make some change here?

Comment: please explain more, because i don't understant exacly what to do? i tried many things, but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a well formed xml document must contain a root(parent) node, the xml that you have shown contains a root node which is not closed. Please close that one.\

Next, I have done a quick change to make it work for IE only, you can update it to work for other browsers, PFB the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fetchMessage(el) {

        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "chapter.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;


        // var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('chapter');
        var item = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//" + el.value).text;


        document.getElementById("message").value = item;


    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="">
<label for="textfield1">
</label>
<input style="border-style: inset" maxlength="70" size="90" type="text" name="" id="message" />
</form>
<table>
    <p style="font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva'" align="right">
        chapter
        <select style="width: 100px" name="lessons" onchange="fetchMessage(this);">
            <option>lesson_1</option>
            <option>lesson_2</option>
            <option>lesson_3</option>
            <option>lesson_4</option>
            <option>lesson_5</option>
            <option>lesson_6</option>
            <option>lesson_7</option>
            <option>lesson_8</option>
            <option>lesson_9</option>
            <option>lesson_10</option>
            <option>lesson_11</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. I test in IE 9 and doesn't works. why? why use "document.getElementById("message").value = item;"
maybe the id "message" it's wrong? i don't use the tag "message" in xml file.

Comment: ok my friend it's works perfect. but i change the Id to "lesson".thanks a lot!